# When do we use the app access token and user access token?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-authentication

Take for example, when using the Koala ruby gem

To access the graph api, we initialize the graph object using the user token key. This is clear, since it contains information that we got from the successful authentication

To access the realtimeupdates api, we initialize the realtimeupdates object using the app access key, which does not seem to have require any user specific authentication information

So, when does facebook require which token?

Comment: You can check the [authentication doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) provided by faceebook for clarification.

Comment: i read it, it is just really complicated, and i need to know the difference for this specific case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a detailed explanation on OAuth site. [Link here](http://www.sociallipstick.com/?p=239)

Comment: @naveen- plz check which link you have put for reference that is not available

Comment: This link is a dead one